# How to find out if an android device has back and menu button as part of screen

Tags: android, touchscreen

I see in shops now that device (mostly tablets) have the back and menu buttons as part of the actual screen. As I can't afford another device and mine has back and menu buttons not part of the screen, will my app be able to make use of these if it uses the whole screen. I am using

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

to make it full screen.

If these buttons do get lost is there a way of finding this out, so as to put on screen alternatives for such devices. Also note that I am using `minSdkVersion="7"`, meaning I would like it to work on anything from `2.1 upwards.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu button was removed in Honeycomb. You can check API version and blindly assume if it is Honeycomb, then Menu button is not there by default (it will be added when using legacy application though). You can check API version that way:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
  // no menu button by default..
}
```

These control buttons (home, back and recent apps) are always part of the screen, even in full screen (it can be dimmed, but not removed)

EDIT: however on-screen "Menu" key is not present in Honecomb **by default**, when you launch legacy application that is not build with targetSdk=11 (or above) then Android will show you that button (otherwise user would not be able to use the app fully). In general - if your app does **NOT** need menu button at all, then set targetSdk to Honeycomb and up. If you need it, set targetSdk to lower value and Android will take care of this case

Comment: thanks for answer. So can I assume any device with android version before Honeycomb has one and then anything to come after will not?

Comment: Yes and no. See my edited answer. From your question I think you try to solve problem that not really exists as OS takes care of such sceenario (as there are many apps not updated since HC) so my answer would really "you do not need to bother at all- Android will take care of your app".

Comment: Can I ask how will android "take care of this case" ? I'm developing camera app, I have there full screen layout without title and Im using hardware menu button to show options menu with "Record" button.
Unfortunately there isnt any hardware `menu` button on HTC desire C, so how should android take care of this?